# How to know all the conditional defines in a project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How it is possible to see all the conditional defines for a Delphi project?

I can define something in project options, but there are some "defaults" and I don't know where to look for. Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the sources of conditional definitions that I can think of:

1. The pre-defined conditionals.
2. The conditionals specified in the project options.
3. The conditionals specified at the command line.
4. The conditionals specified in the source code (often in .inc files).

Now, I think you are asking about item 1 on this list, the pre-defined conditionals. The Delphi documentation has a comprehensive lists of these:

- [Predefined Conditionals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29#Predefined_Conditionals).
- [Compiler Versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions).

Comment: I am confused becuase on the same machine with XE2 on some projects I have errors (becuase some code in between some IFDEF tries to be compiled) while in other projects it doesntì. Anyway I use the same libraries and I didn't explcitly DEFINE anything. What could be the reason of this different behaviour?

Comment: What is the conditional in question? Is it one of the pre-defined conditionals?

Comment: This answers my question, but the problem I was trying to solve ended up to be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130615/why-jpeg-is-accepted-in-the-uses-clause-in-some-projects-and-in-others-vcl-imagi

Answer (score 1):

I have been wondering this same question, as I believe it is valuable to look at source code and know the value of the conditional symbols
 ( since there are ways to ask other preprocessors (like gcc) to list the symbols they think are defined )

I ended up scanning all the source files for {$IF*  } type lines and 
potential {$DEFINE } collecting names that might be defined.

Then, since most of the flags were stored in one or two {$I included} files,
I wrote a stand alone command line tool that
Included all the configuration files, then auto-generated
{$IFDEF }WriteLn("");{$ENDIF}
for each symbol

This created an output file with all the defined symbols

( Also searching for preprocessor tools )