# Why Jpeg is accepted in the uses clause in some projects and in others vcl.imaging.jpeg is required?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am updating some projects to XE2 and I don't understand why on some projects

```
uses jpeg;
```

is accepted

and in other i need to write

```
uses vcl.imaging.jpeg;
```

Could you explain me please?

Comment: for firemonkey its `vcl.imnaging.jpeg;`
and normally its i think `vcl.imnaging.jpeg;
`  check this https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=399715&tstart=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is down to the the unit scope names setting in the project options for your various projects.

If you have `Vcl.Imaging` included in that setting then you don't need to fully specify the unit scope. Typically, old projects that are upgraded from previous Delphi versions will have `Vcl.Imaging` included in the unit scope names setting. New projects do not.

This is described in the [documentation for Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names).

Comment: Ok I can stop banging my head against the wall now!

Comment: This by the way solves my other quesiton I posted, I thought they were unrelated problems but it was the same. Basically the prolem was not on conditional define but only on unit scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130305/delphi-how-to-know-all-the-conditional-defines-in-a-project